# Creating Dynamic JS with Yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2

I'm attempting to add a google map onto my page with borders draw in dynamically according to variable.

I'm confused about where I should be doing this in Yii. The Asset files just seem to be a way to have certain pages load certain static js, but there doesn't seem to be a way to have the javascript build from variables generated from the PHP side.

I think I should be using the `registerJs()` [function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html), but I'm unclear on the general way to generate the code that is passed in here as it seems to only want the full java script. Do I simple create a variable in the controller and assign the javascript code-string there? This doesn't seem like the best way going forward if I want a front end coder to come in and tweak the code for it, when it's buried in the controller.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this (Not with Google Maps, but with register JS):

```
$script = "Javascript here, with your ".$phpvariables." in it.";
$this->registerJs($script, View::POS_END);
```

> View::POS_HEAD for head section.
>
> View::POS_BEGIN for right after opening .
>
> View::POS_END for right before closing .
>
> View::POS_READY for executing code on document ready event. This will
>   register jQuery automatically.
>
> View::POS_LOAD for executing code on document load event. This will
>   register jQuery automatically.

This is in a view file, and it uses the View Class registerJs().

**EDIT:** Note that by using POS_LOAD and POS_READY, the method will automatically register the jQuery js file and enclose it within jQuery(window).load() or jQuery(document).ready().

Comment: Also, one way to keep all these snippets of code together is to use view files; just have a collection of view files that just create and register various javascripts. Then you can render these as needed in your main view files, but they are re-usable and all in the one place should you need to edit them.